# Can't add additional answers on Teams (Ubuntu/Chrome)

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, browser-support

Not sure if this is the right place for this, but I have been running into what seems to be a system ([Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)) and browser (Chrome) specific issue with Teams.

I have been adding a number of questions with self-answers to start out a Team page. This generally works fine until I try to add additional answers. This should bring up a dialog box that says

> Are you sure you want to add another answer? You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

While this works with Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 and in Chrome on Windows/Android/Mac, for some reason there is no response with Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04.

It doesn't seem to be an issue with pop-up blocking (I don't know if the textbox even qualifies as a pop up) as I have allowed pop-ups within the Team. Am I missing something on my end or is this a browser bug?

I get two errors and three issues in the developer window:

#### Errors

```
Error connecting controller

'[aria-controls="{POPOVER_ID}"] required'
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Queue')
    at full.en.js?v=445e015ca239:2
    at Object.<anonymous> (47:65)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.e.<computed> [as resolve] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at stub.en.js?v=61ffd6e5b427:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (stub.en.js?v=61ffd6e5b427:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.e.<computed> [as resolve] (jquery.min.js:2)
```

#### Issues

- Two instances of "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform"
- One instance of Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode

The same error also prevents me from closing the text box over the question that reads

> Increase the chances of getting an answer by notifying team members

### Update

Interestingly, this doesn't seem to be a general Teams issue. I'm a moderator on *[Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/tour)* and I had no issue adding answers on the Moderator Team's page. This is despite having the same error messages in browser console. Some sort of difference between free and business tier Teams?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I've edited in the error messages

Comment: huh, looks like an issue with Stacks...

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

For whatever reason, when I initially go to a question, the answer button does not work (won't bring up pop-up text or editor window). However, if I back out of a page and then go forward into it, I can then post an answer. Simply refreshing the page does not have this effect; I explicitly have to go back-and-forth in history to get it to work.

Comment: Just guessing, but I think it works when you go back and forwards again it's displaying the initial state of the page and thinks you haven't posted yet.